# Trouble displaying results correctly from FOREACH loop

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I switched my code to PDO and I almost there, except for this part where all results from a query are supposed to be displayed with a foreach statement. I know the data is being fetched properly and is correctly stored in $row2.

What I need to do is get take the 'position' variable from $results2 and add 1 to it and then run the foreach loops where position is equal to that new number...

BEFORE I SWITCHED TO PDO, my code was working perfectly and this did correctly display the 2 expected results:

```
$cont = $results2[0]->position;;
$cont++;

foreach ($results2 as $resulting) {
if ( $results2[0]->position = $cont )
{
echo "<hr><br><br>" . $resulting->text . "&nbsp;" . "   <b>Suggested by: $resulting-
>display_name </b><br>|<b> <a href=\"$url\">Approve this contribution</a></b> | <b><a
href=\"$url\">delete this suggestion</a></b> |";
}
}
```

But now, the foreach only returns the same first result twice after the conversion to PDO, which looks like this:

//NEW PDO CODE--DOESN'T DISPLAY BOTH RESULTS:

```
$results2->execute();
$row2 = $results2->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$cont = $row2[0]['position'];
$cont++;

foreach ($row2 as $resulting) {
if ( $row2[0]['position'] == $cont )
{
echo "<hr><br><br>" . $row2[0][text] . "&nbsp;" . "   <b>Suggested by:" . $row2[0]
[display_name] . "</b><br>|<b> <a href=\"$url\">Approve this contribution</a></b> | <b>
<a href=\"$url/?WID=$resulting->WID\">delete this suggestion</a></b> |";
}
}
```

Comment: shouldn't there be two equals signs for comparison and not assignment?

Comment: If I change = to == I get no results. But if I keep it as = then I get the first result.

Comment: you do realize that that if statement has no purpose then? you are just assigning the value and its returning true so the echo happens

Comment: Well, I'm going by the fact that my code was working perfectly before I switched to PDO. See my code under ADDiTIONAL in my post to see what was working before the change to PDO. Adding an equal sign somehow returned no results instead of the correct results.

Comment: I think the problem is that I cannot use $resulting when looping through results as defined in the foreach when doing PDO?

Comment: You need to show the code that comes before what you've posted. Without knowing how you've assigned `$row2`, it's hard to say exactly what's going on here.

Comment: Also, the if statement is simply augmenting the position by 1 for the foreach loop. Not really trying to do a comparison there, which is why it worked previously before switching to PDO

Comment: @Patrick @...just updated original post to show all code...

Comment: This `$row2[0][position]` should be throwing a warning (or maybe a notice?). You most likely mean `$row2[0]['position']`. You make that mistake twice.

Comment: Well I heeded the 'position' advice and set to == and it's strange: I get two results as I should, but the same record is just shown twice/repeated, rather than showing me both different records. It's like it know there are two results so I tries to show two, but instead just shows the first result twice...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your old code was fetching an array of objects, whereas your new code is fetching an array of arrays (indicated by `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`).

So while `$results2[0]->position` used to work, you mistakenly replaced it with `$row2[0][position]`.  However, `position` needs to be quoted in the second case since it is an array index.

If you had all of your error reporting turned on, you would have easily seen this.

The same applies to `$row2[0][text]` and `$row2[0][display_name]`. In addition to the lack of quotes on these indexes, you probably really want `$resulting` instead of `$row[0]` since `$row[0]` will give you the same values each time through the loop. So those should probably be changed to `$resulting['text']` and `$resulting['display_name']`

So replace all instances of `$row2[0][position]` with `$row2[0]['position']`.  Also, heed the advice of John Ruddell.

Comment: +1 nice catch patrick i thought I had seen position set to something so i figured it was still a variable

Comment: Sort of figured it out...I want to add 1 to $row[position] (my first query before this one] so the position becomes 2. I was adding to $row2[position] which was making 3. So now I need the foreach to take the results where $row2[position] == cont (but still just returns first of the two results when I do this). And as for [position] vs ['position'] it works either way--maybe a wordpress thing?

Comment: Well I heeded the 'position' advice and set to == and it's strange: I get two results as I should, but the same record is just shown twice/repeated, rather than showing me both different records. It's like it know there are two results so I tries to show two, but instead just shows the first result twice...

Comment: That's because you're displaying the values from `$row2[0]`, which will always be the same. What you probably want is `$resulting['text']` and `$resulting['display_name']` (notice that you made the same quote mistake on those too).

Comment: @Patrick Q THAT'S IT! I knew it was an issue with my foreach loop. Didn't know I could take the newly defined $resulting and do $resulting['text']. Awesome, thanks. And FYI, the quotes are unnecessary. Works both ways. If you post as answer I can accept

Comment: I already updated my answer.  The quotes are _not_ unnecessary though.  You might be getting lucky that your system is making the correct "guess" in this case.  If you get into the habit of doing that, you're going to get yourself in trouble some day.  See the difference between [this](http://3v4l.org/rLSud) (no quotes) and [this](http://3v4l.org/NegSp) (with quotes).

Comment: Warning heeded. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE:** this is not an answer... its just a way for me to clarify what I was saying in comments because its hard to show code in comments.

**GENERAL IF CODE LOGIC:**

```
if (true){
    // code will always execute on true
}

if (false){
    // code will never execute on false
}
```

**sample:**

```
$key = "12345";
if($key){
    // will always be executed because this is a true statement. 
}
```

**your code:**

```
if ( $row2[0]['position'] = $cont ){
    // will always execute because the assignment is true
}
```

**NOW:**
with all that aside.. if nothing is happening when you run it with `==` that means that the count is not equal to the `$row[0][position]` so its a false statement and the code inside the if does not get executed.

**RECOMMENDATION:**

try putting an `echo $cont;` and `echo $row2[0]['position'];` before the if statement to see whats going on.

Comment: Gotchya. It makes sense, but why would it work perfectly in my original code which you can see above? Nothing changed except how I had to rewrite the foreach part for the PDO...